# Соединить две таблицы с ManyToMany отношением в Django и сохранять запись в промежуточную таблицу

Tags: django

У меня есть две таблицы с отношением ManyToMany(`Service` и `ApiKey`),а так же третья, промежуточная таблица, которая соединяет их. У меня есть формы для добавления записи в бд на основе модели для этих таблиц. Хотелось, чтобы при добавлении `Service` был ещё список, какой ключ к нему привязать.
Как это сделать?? ?

**Service:**

```
class Service(models.Model):
    flow = models.ForeignKey(
        Flow,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='services_flows'
    )
    currency = models.ForeignKey(
        Currency,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='services_currencies'
    )
    contractor = models.ForeignKey(
        Contractor,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='services_contractors',
    )
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    callback_url = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )
    definition = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=dict())
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    charge_strategy = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='default')
    routine = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=dict())
    service_key = models.ManyToManyField(ApiKey, through='ServiceKey',through_fields=('service', 'apikey'), related_name='key')
```

**Apikey:**

```
class ApiKey(models.Model):
    open_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    restrict_ip = models.BooleanField()
    ip = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=True), size=8, blank=True, null=True
    )
    valid_to_date = models.DateField()
    restrict_methods = models.BooleanField()
    allowed_methods = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
        size=8, blank=True, null=True
    )
    forbidden_methods = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
        size=8, blank=True, null=True
    )
```

**Service_key - промежуточная таблица для соединения двух таблиц:**
[image]

**ServiceForm:**

```
class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
    super(ServiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Service
    fields = [
        'name', 'amount', 'callback_url', 'charge_strategy',
        'description', 'definition', 'routine', 'contractor',
        'flow', 'currency', 'service_key'
    ]

    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'name'
        }),
        'amount': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'amount'
        }),
        'callback_url': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'callback url'
        }),
        'charge_strategy': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'charge strategy',
            'readonly': 'True',
        }),
        'description': Textarea(attrs={
            'cols': 40,
            'rows': 5,
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT + 'sf-sm-fs',
            'placeholder': 'description',
        }),
        'definition': Textarea(attrs={
            'cols': 40,
            'rows': 5,
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT + 'sf-sm-fs',
            'placeholder': 'definition',
            'value': '',
            'data-is-json': 'True',
        }),
        'routine': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'contractor': forms.Select(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
        }),
        'flow': forms.Select(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'cols': 40, 'rows': 5,
        }),
        'currency': forms.Select(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'cols': 4, 'rows': 5,
        }),
         'service_key': forms.Select(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
        })
    }

    labels = {
        'name': 'name',
        'amount': 'amount',
        'callback_url': 'callback_url',
        'charge_strategy': 'charge_strategy',
        'description': 'description',
        'definition': 'definition',
        'routine': 'routine',
        'contractor': 'contractor',
        'flow': 'flow',
        'currency': 'currency',
        'service_key': 'service_key'
    }
```

**View  Service:**

```
class CreateServiceView(
    SuccessMessageMixin,
    CustomPermissionRequired,
    CreateView
):
    model = Service

    template_name = 'db_visual/create_service.html'

    form_class = ServiceForm

    permission_required = (
        'db_visual.add_service',
    )

    success_message = "service %(name)s created!"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreateServiceView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user

        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy(
            'update_service',
            kwargs={'service_id': self.object.id}
        )
```

**service_key model:**

```
class ServiceKey(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(
        Service,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='service',
        null=True
    )
    apikey = models.ForeignKey(
        ApiKey,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='apikey',
        null=True
    )
```

UPD: Объединить их получилось, но выдаёт ошибку при попытке сохранить:

```
Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use db_visual.ServiceKey's Manager instead.
```

То есть, в `service` запись сохраняется а в `service_key` не может, а мне очень надо, чтобы при сохранении формы, запись в эту таблицу сохранялась. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже задавали 2 таких вопроса. Посмотрите [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724203/another-cannot-set-values-on-a-manytomanyfield-which-specifies-an-intermediary-m):

> Don't commit when saving your save. As documented here if you specify
>   commit=True it will try to write the M2M mapping at the same time. You
>   don't want that to happen.
>
> By specifying a vale of False instead, you can call save_m2m later to
>   save the mapping, or create your own mapping instead. You need to do
>   the latter and the rest of your code is already doing the right thing
>   for that.

И [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091328/django-cannot-set-values-on-a-manytomanyfield-which-specifies-an-intermediary-mo):

> The RelatedManager.add(), create(), remove(), set(), get_or_create(),
>   and update_or_create() methods are now allowed on many-to-many
>   relationships with intermediate models. The new through_defaults
>   argument is used to specify values for new intermediate model
>   instance(s).

В [офф. документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили. Но я так и не могу понять/записать решение, которое поможет мне сохранить записи и в таблицу `service` и в промежуточную таблицу `servicekey`. Буду очень рад, если напишете пример.

Comment: @PavelKutsubin А какую версию Django используете?

Comment: @АндрейП. 2.0.7

Comment: @PavelKutsubin Тогда ни как потому как "

As of the Django 2.2 release you can also specify a through_defaults on the field in order to use add, create and assignment:    The RelatedManager.add(), create(), remove(), set(), get_or_create(), and update_or_create() methods are now allowed on many-to-many relationships with intermediate models. The new through_defaults argument is used to specify values for new intermediate model instance(s).In your case since all the fields already have defaults it might just work in 2.2.

Comment: @PavelKutsubin т.е. либо обновится до 2.2.0 либо городить кастомные решения.

Comment: @АндрейП., Если накачу 2.2, то моё решение будет верным?

Comment: @PavelKutsubin Ничего криминального вроде не вижу. Попробуйте.